# If $\int_a^b f\, d\alpha $ exists for all continuous $f$ then $\alpha$ is of bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis, alternative-proof, riemann-integration

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2055518/72031) the following theorem is proved:

> **Theorem**: Let $\alpha:[a, b] \to\mathbb {R} $ be a function such that the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $$\int_{a} ^{b} f(x) \, d\alpha(x) $$ exists for all continuous functions $f:[a, b] \to\mathbb {R} $. Then $\alpha $ is of bounded variation on $[a, b] $.

However the linked answer uses Banach Steinhaus theorem to prove it.

> Is there any proof which does not use theorems from functional analysis and is rather based on the usual theorems dealing with Riemann-Stieltjes integration?

Comment: I doubt such a proof exists. The setting is the natural habitat of functional analysis: a linear functional (integrating against some measure) defined on a normed space (the space of all continuous functions on $[a,b]$).

Comment: I wonder if for “simple” concrete examples like $\alpha(x) = x \sin(1/x)$ it is possible to find a “concrete” function $f$ such that $\int_0^1 f(x) d\alpha(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: @MartinR: I had forgotten about this question. It appears to be handled elsewhere on mathse: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2427978/72031

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: That is a very nice answer, thanks for the response and the link!

Comment: Here is another one https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1864023/42969 (and the answer looks wrong to me). What do you suggest: Close that one as a duplicate, or as off-topic (missing context)?

Comment: @MartinR: the best would be to close for lack of context and add a comment linking the right dupe target. In case you vote to close as off topic I will also cast the vote to close it.